# Magnific popup transparent png as grey

Tags: javascript, css, background, transparency, magnific-popup

I am facing problem with magnific popup - when transparent PNG opens, the transparent parts are grey. I have searched for solution but without success. While changing img.mfp img background color to white it changes but it shows the white color and that is not good for me. I need to have it just like the whole background - black with opacity 0.01 (if I am not mistaken)...I did not changed any relevant code in CSS or JS related to Magnific popup.
Can anyone help? Thanks in forward

Comment: show us some code, what have you tried so far?

Comment: I have uploaded it for test purposes to [link](http://vlkotech.sk/augustin/index.html)
I have tried the tricks with background colors and opacity but no change onto wanting result. For test purposes its the very first picture of "zahradna architektura" and the picture now is just transparent square of 200px. Thanks for any advice

Comment: This was doing my head in, nice one! :D

Comment: Please do not edit solution announcements into the question. Accept (i.e. click the "tick" next to it) one of the existing answer, if there are any. You can also create your own answer, and even accept it, if your solution is not yet covered by an existing answer.

Answer (score 0):

to add a white background under the popup image I use this code

```
.mfp-figure:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 40px;
    bottom: 40px;
    display: block;
    right: 0;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    z-index: -1;
    box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1); /* white background */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this will help.

```
img.mfp-img {
    background-color: white;
    background-clip: content-box;
}
```